# Applescript + InDesign Selecting Body Rows In Table

Tags: excel, automation, applescript, adobe-indesign

I am currently trying to automate some data formatting.  The source data is formatted in Excel. The inDesign template is already formatted. I can right click the table and select body rows then paste the data and it looks beautiful.  I am looking to remove this step but am unable to figure out how to get applescript to select the table and body rows of the inDesign template. 
Neither of the following seem to work.

```
set selection to body rows of table 1 of active document
```

```
select body rows of table 1 of active document
```

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the `select` command only works for a single row, and not all of the rows in a selected table.

Essentially, you must go row by and decide the `row type`. Once you've decided the row is a `body row`, you can select it.

The syntax for adding a selected row to another selected row is super tricky, especially without an example. See the complete script below.

```
    tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"

    set allBodyRows to every row of every table of every story of active document whose row type is body row

    set bodyRow to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to (count allBodyRows)
        set bodyRow to item i of allBodyRows
        if i = 1 then
            select bodyRow
        else
            select bodyRow existing selection add to
        end if
    end repeat

    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reference your table differently. Try this:

```
 set allTables to every table of every story of active document

 set myTable to item 1 of allTables
```

Then you should be able to select rows:

```
tell table myTable

select first row

end tell
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try.

Answer (score -1):

```
--author by RyuAutodidacte
tell application "Adobe InDesign 2020"
tell active document
    --When the selection is a text frame
    set FirstBodyCell to index of first cell of table 1 of selection whose row type is body row
    set LastBodyCell to index of last cell of table 1 of selection whose row type is body row
    select cells FirstBodyCell thru LastBodyCell of table 1 of selection
end tell
end tell
```